# AWS EC2 AMI launch with user-data

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to launch my own AMI using user-data so that it can run a script and then terminate.

So I launched an Ec2 Windows Base and configure it to have all the tools I need (NodeJS etc) and saved my script to C:\Projects\index.js.

I then saved it as an Image.

So I then used the console to launch an EC2 from my new AMI with the user-data of

```
node C:\Projects\index.js --uuid=1
</powershell>
```

If I run that command having RDP into the EC2 it works, so it seems that the userdata did not run when the Image was started.

Having read some of the other questions and answers it could be because the AMI created was made from an Instance that started already. So the userdata did not persist.

Can anyone advise me on how I can launch my AMI with a custom userdata each time? (as the UUID will change)

Thanks

Comment: Suggest you enhance your userdata to echo a few comments to file so you can see afterwards if it's actually executing. Also verify that node is on the PATH and that C:\Projects\index.js actually exists. Some examples at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html

Comment: If you are launching a new instance, the the User Data _will_ execute. Check you logs at: `C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Log\UserdataExecution.log`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that worked for me is to run Sysprep with EC2Launch.

The issue is that AWS doesn't reestablish the route to the profile service (169.254.169.254) in your custom AMI. See response by SanjitPatel in this post. So when I tried to use my custom AMI to create spot requests, my new instances were failing to find user data.

Shutting down with Sysprep, essentially forces AWS re-do all setup work on the instance, as if it were run for the first time. So when you create your instance, shut it down with Sysprep and then create your custom AMI, AWS will setup the profile service route correctly for the new instances and execute your user data. This also avoids manually changing Windows Tasks and executing user data on subsequent boots, as persist tag does.

Here is a quick step-by-step:

1.Create an instance using one of the AWS Windows AMIs (Windows Server 2016 Nano Server doesn't support Sysprep) and passing your desired user data (this may be optional, but good to make sure AWS wires setup scripts correctly to handle user data).

2.Customize your instance as needed.

3.Shut down your instance with Sysprep. Just open EC2LaunchSettings application and click "Shutdown with Sysprep".

4.Create your custom AMI from the instance you just shut down.

5.Use your custom AMI to create other instances, passing user data on instance creation. User data will be executed on instance launch. In my case, I used Spot Request screen, which had a User Data text box.
Hope this helps!